# Issue with tidytext() : unable to apply unnest_tokens to dataframe

Tags: r, rstudio, tidytext

I've been trying to apply unnest_tokens from tidytext in a dataframe column to generate common bigrams and trigrams. Theyre short texts from > 200 articles. They're also a column subset from a larger csv.

I've tried the following , to no avail:
1. setting stringsasfactors = FALSE
2. used unnest_, unnest_tokens_.

Example :
`bookparagraphs.csv`

```
a<- data.frame("texts" = bookparagraphs$text[1:10], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

str(a)

'data.frame':   10 obs. of  1 variable:
$ text: Factor w/ 6552 levels
```

> Error in check_input(x) : 
>         Input must be a character vector of any length or a list of character
>         vectors, each of which has a length of 1.***

However, tm_map works wonderfully when I converted my texts > corpus > DTM etc . I'm able to count and review word co-occurrences just fine.

I'd like to get better at using tidytext, hence I'm looking to finding out how this works and where I went wrong.

Appreciate any suggestions ! Thank you.

Comment: Problem is we have no access to your data. Use `dput` to add sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get in tidytext is because texts is a factor. This means your bookparagraphs$text is a factor. Probably from reading in bookparagraphs.csv. When you just use `a <- data.frame("texts" = bookparagraphs$text[1:10], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`, the stringAsFactors has no effect on the factor bookparagraphs$text. Either read the bookparagraphs.csv with `stringAsFactors = FALSE` or use readr to load the data. Or use:

```
a <- data.frame("texts" = as.character(bookparagraphs$text[1:10]), stringAsFactors = FALSE)
```

This will coerce the bookparagraphs$text to a character vector, and the stringAsFactors = FALSE prevents it from being turned into a factor again.

After this, you can use `unnest_tokens` without an issue.